# making the width of drop down bigger

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have the following code on my page for dropdown list box. No matter how much I try, I cannot make the width of the dropdown box bigger. Below is my code:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-1">&nbsp;</div>
  <label for="inputTitles" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><asp:Label ID="lblDocType" runat="server"></asp:Label></label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select class="form-control" aria-label="Default select example">
      <option selected>--Please Select a title from the list-</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to put this style sheet in the `asp:DropDownList` class:

```html
<style>
.ddlwidth {
  width: 1000px !important;
}
</style>
```

```
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control ddlwidth" ID="ddlDocType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DocType_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" Width="700" >
```

That didn't work either. If I remove the `form-control` and then increase the width of the `dropdownList` then the width becomes bigger. The reason, I don't want to remove the `form-control` class because I want to keep the look and feel of `form-control` class.

How can I increase the width of the `dropdownlist` box without removing the `form-control` class?

Below is what it looks like on my web page:

[image: dropdown preview]

Comment: Use `w-100` on the `select` element

Comment: How do I use w-100 on the select element? can you give me an example.

Comment: Editor’s note: do not reject good edits from community members that have to through peer review. The fact that you, as a post author, can unilaterally approve/reject edits does not mean you should do so on a whim. I reapplied the rejected edit in the meantime – please do not do that again. See [FAQ on Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/786798) if you want to learn more.

Comment: @rimi use it as `<select class="w-100">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your style sheet:

```
 .form-control {
        width: 394px;
```

And then:

```
<select class="form-control" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>--Please Select a title from the list-</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```